# how to make a query Match with OR condition in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

How to write a match with `OR`condition in OrientDB?

EG: I want to find files the user have `accessTo` and files the which the group user belongs have access to.

```
select   from (
MATCH
{class: user, where:(userid='User1'), as: u},
{as:u}-accessTo->{class: so,where:(projectId='Project1'), as: r},
{as:u}-memberOf->{class: group, where:(projectId='Project1')}-accessTo-> 
{class: so,as: r}
RETURN r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no OR option in MATCH statement, so you have to use two queries and a unionAll:

```
select  unionAll($a, $b) 
LET
   $a = (MATCH
      {class: user, where:(userid='User1'), as: u},
      {as:u}-accessTo->{class: so,where:(projectId='Project1'), as: r},
   RETURN r),
   $b = (MATCH
      {class: user, where:(userid='User1'), as: u},
      {as:u}-memberOf->{class: group, where:(projectId='Project1')}-accessTo-> 
      {class: so,as: r}
   RETURN r),
)
```